# NVD3 lineChart - Fill area above the line, instead of below

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm developing a chart very similar to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/L6nfq/

But instead of filling the blue area below the blue line, I want to fill the area above it. What should I do in this case?

I know that there is a simple way of doing this using pure D3.js (through the functions `y0` and `y1`), but I want a solution using NVD3 library.

It is possible to make a small change in this jsfiddle to fill the blue area above the line instead of the area below it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way I can see using the functionality provided by `nvd3`, so I'd just hack it in with base `d3`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return chart.xScale()(d.x); })
    .y0(0)
    .y1(function(d) { return chart.yScale()(d.y); });
    var t = d3.select(".nv-series-2"),
        d = t.datum().values;
  t.append("path")
    .attr("d", area(d))
    .style("fill", "steelblue");
}, 10);
```

---

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L6nfq/33/).

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

How about this craziness:

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) {
      return chart.xScale()(d.x);
    })
    .y0(0)
    .y1(function(d) {
      return chart.yScale()(d.y);
    });
  function addArea() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      d3.selectAll("#cust-fill").remove();
      d3.selectAll('.nv-group')
        .each(function(d) {
          if (d.key === "Another sine wave") {
            var t = d3.select(this),
              d = t.datum().values;
            t.append("path")
              .attr("id", "cust-fill")
              .attr("d", area(d))
              .style("fill", d.color)
              .style("opacity", ".3");
          }
        })
    }, 100);
  }
  nv.dispatch.render_end = addArea;
  chart.dispatch.stateChange = addArea;
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6nfq/36/).

Comment: It works at first, but if you play selecting and deselecting some series, it stops working. Is there some workaround?

Comment: Wow! It works almost perfectly. I'm going to use it.Thank you!